# How do I access the value of this particular xml node?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm transforming an XML document to HTML, and wish to pick out a few particular elements (for use in the `head.title` of the HTML page).

My source XML looks thusly:

```
<document>
  <vars>
    <var name="serialno">
      12345                     <<--- I want THIS value
    </var>
    <var name="rev-date" rev="old">
      2000-01-01
    </var>
    <var name="rev-date" rev="new">
      2011-05-01                <<--- ...and also THIS value
    </var>
    ... more vars
  </vars>
    ... more data
</document>
```

Now, the serial would be something along the lines of "`<xsl:value-of select="/vars/var@serialno"/>`", but I can't figure out how to address the `var` with that particular `name`. Similarly for the revision date, except that I need to specify two attributes. **How do I do that?**

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two alternative solutions for each of your two questions. This is actually an XPath question.

Comment: @Dimitre, thanks for the tag adjustment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/vars/var[@name = 'serialno']/text()
```

to obtain the desired text node or just

```
string(/*/vars/var[@name = 'serialno'])
```

to get the desired string.

**And use**:

```
/*/vars/var
       [@name = 'rev-date' 
      and
        @rev = 'new'
       ]/text()
```

to obtain the 2nd desired text node or just

```
string(/*/vars/var
           [@name = 'rev-date' 
          and
            @rev = 'new'
           ]/text()
      )
```

to get its string value.

Comment: `<head>Serial: <xsl:value-of select="/*/vars/var[@name = 'serialno']/text()"/>
</title><head>` worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:value-of select="document/vars/var[@name='serialno']"/>
```

AND

```
<xsl:value-of select="document/vars/var[@name='rev-date' and @rev='new']"/>
```

To test this out go to xmlper.com and key this as the XSL:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
    <html xsl:version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


     <xsl:value-of select="document/vars/var[@name='serialno']"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="document/vars/var[@name='rev-date' and @rev='new']"/>

    </html>
```

And this as the XML document:

```
<document>
  <vars>
    <var name="serialno">
      12345                    
    </var>
    <var name="rev-date" rev="old">
      2000-01-01
    </var>
    <var name="rev-date" rev="new">
      2011-05-01              
    </var>
    ... more vars
  </vars>

</document>
```

Comment: This sounds very concise and alluring, except it doesn't seem to work. I'll try some more...

Comment: Hi - I tested this on www.xmlper.com.  I've attached code above which you can use to test it (unfortunately the website doesn't allow me to save and send a link onto you).

Comment: Ah, I was missing a leading slash, `/document/...`